# Lubuntu not displaying native resolution?

Tags: lubuntu, display-resolution

I recently installed Lubuntu on one of my junk machines. I want to use it as an entertainment center in the living room for everyone to use. While I was setting up the PC, I used a cheapo monitor, which Lubuntu picked up as 1280x1024, it's native resolution, even without drivers. Now, I tried to plug it into my TV (native 1080p) and I went in to change the resolution. The only options were 640x480, 800x600, and 1024x768. Can I have some help? Please keep in mind that I am pretty new to Linux as a whole and still have a lot to learn. Thanks!

Comment: What graphics card do you have?

Comment: I'm using the intergrated graphics on this machine, which has a Core 2 Duo E4400. I have another DVI/S-VIDEO card somewhere, but it's generic, my TV doesn't have a DVI port, and I can't find an S-video cable.

Comment: S-Video doesn't natively support over 800x600 and can't go over 1024x768, so that wouldn't be very helpful. Are you connecting to the TV through VGA?

Comment: Yes, it's the only port I have.

Comment: Hmm. VGA is capable of way over 1080p. Are you sure this TV is 1920x1080, or does it just say it can support 1080p video (misleading advertising)?

Comment: Almost positive, have a cable box hooked up via HDMI. It actually might be 720p, but I assumed the exact res wouldn't matter. Would love at least 720p though, as it only likes up to 1024x768.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues connecting to a TV although mine was 1368x768, so my exact answer won't apply.  But you may be able to use the same method.

You can try to add a "mode" by opening a terminal and typing `cvt 1920 1080 60` (if 1920 x 1080 is the resolution you want, otherwise change the numbers). This will generate a line of data that you need for the next commands.  Copy all the line of data except for the word Modeline, and type the command

`xrandr --newmode ****`  where *** is the data that you copied

For the next command you need to know your display output name. It's probably VGA1, but make sure by typing `xrandr` by itself. Now type the command

`xrandr --addmode *** XXXX` where *** is your display name and XXXX is the first part of the data line, the part in quotes.  Mine was 1368x768_60.00

Finally try switching to the new output by typing

`xrandr --output *** --mode XXXX` where the fields mean the same thing as in the previous command.

If this all works, there is a way to automate it at login.  Post a comment and I'll add that to the answer if you get this far.

Edit: my exact commands, to use as an example are:

```
xrandr --newmode "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA1 1368x768_60.00
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1368x768_60.00
```

Edit 2: Assuming the output is VGA1, your commands could look like

```
xrandr --newmode "1280x720_60.00" 74.50 1280 1344 1472 1664 720 723 728 748 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA1 1280x720_60.00
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1280x720_60.00
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! It's getting late where I live, so I'll probably try it tomorrow and post results. Hopefully it does!

Comment: My display is going nuts! Any help? I actually went to 720p just to be safe, then the display freaked out! What happened?

Comment: Oh ok, just saw your edit. I didn't put the hsync and vsync flags. Could that be the problem?

Comment: A reboot will get rid of any effects from these commands.  What was the output from `cvt`?

Comment: All of it or just the part it wants me to copy?

Comment: You should copy everything on the Modeline except the word Modeline.

Comment: Right. Forgot how to do code formatting so plain text it is.           "1280x720_60.00" 74.50 1280 1344 1472 1664  720 723 728 748 -hsync +vsync

Comment: @PixelSpark I edited the answer to add some suggested commands, assuming that your video output is VGA1.  If it isn't make the appropriate changes.

Comment: Alright, thanks! I'll try it out when I get home.